# get prefabs from folder then converting to list<GameObject>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get all prefabs in a certain folder and then converting it to a list

my code :

```
this.list = (List<GameObject>) (Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("items")).ToList<GameObject>(); // this code not working   
this.list = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("items").ToList<GameObject>();
```

On the last line I get the following error:

> "UnityEngine.Object[]' does not contain a member `ToList` and the best extension method overload `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ToArray()` is a method that belongs to the Linq namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx). 
Just add `using System.Linq;` to your code.

But also, the second line of code has a problem. It returns a list of `UnityEngine.Object` and you are trying to create a list of `GameObjects`. You can cast it this way:

`var objectsArray = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("items");
this.list = new List<GameObject>(objectsArray.Cast<GameObject>());`

Comment: I added using System.Linq; already; and the errors went out after your edits , but now , it always give me Error in this code : "Debug.Log(list[0].name);":"ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range."

Comment: Well, that's another error, another question. It means your list is empty, because it's trying to access the first element and it doesn't exist. Out of range: even the 0 index is out of range. The load method didn't find any prefab. Try logging the size (count) of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert object to gameObject you can try following code. :)

```
this.list = (List<GameObject>) (Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("items")).ToList<GameObject>();
    List<object> objList;
    objList =  AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("items").ToList<object>();
    List<GameObject> list2 = new List<GameObject>();
    foreach(Object item in objList)
    {
        GameObject obj = item as GameObject;
        list2.Add(obj);
    }
```